# Autofill textbox based on dropdown list selection which is binded from db in asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

This is view part:

In this view part Product name dropdown is retrieved from database , what iam trying to do is after selecting product name, price must be populated in the price textbox. Product name, price and other columns are already stored in db.

```
    <div class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
                <label class="col-sm-8 control-label no-padding-right">Product Name</label>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    @Html.DropDownList("Product_Name", (SelectList)ViewBag.Values, "Please select", new { @id = "populate", @class = "SelectCtrlGHN", onchange = "return get_sbu(this)" })

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

<div class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
                <label class="col-sm-8 control-label no-padding-right">Price</label>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <input type="text" name="Price" class="col-xl-4 col-sm-8" id="pric" />

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Script to retrieve price :

Here i have written script to retrieve price according to the corresponding dropdown list selection in view.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
                            $(document).ready(function() {
                                $('#populate').change(function() {
                                    var str = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
                                    var st = null;
                                    $.ajax('@Url.Action("GetProductData", "Userrolereq")', {
                                        type: 'POST',
                                        dataType: 'json',
                                        data: { 'productID': str },{'amt':st},
                                        success: function(data, status, jqXHR) {
                                            if ("success" === status) {
                                                document.getElementById('#populate').value = data.productID;
                                                document.getElementById('#pric').value = data.amt;
                                            }
                                            if ("productCode" != null) {
                                                document.getElementById('#pric').value = data.amt;
                                            }else {
                                                alert('This Product ID is not valid. Try again!');
                                            }
                                        }
                                    });
                                });
                            });
</script>
```

This is Controller:

From DM_Userreq table in database iam trying to retrieve price from dropdown selection.

```
 public ActionResult GetProductData(string productID)
        {
            string sa = "";
            SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["con"].ConnectionString);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            using (cn)
            {
                cn.Open();
                string que = string.Format("Select Price From DM_Userreq Where Product_Name = '{0}'", productID);
                SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand(que, cn);
                SqlDataReader rd = cm.ExecuteReader();
                while (rd.Read())
                {
                    sb.Append(rd["Price"].ToString() + "</br>");
                    return Json(new { success = true, productCode = sb.Append(rd["Price"].ToString() + "</br>") });
                }
                sa = sb.ToString();

                cn.Close();
            }
            return Json(new { success = false });
        }
```

Comment: `data: "id=" + selected_val` => should this be `data: { id: selected_val }`? Also `data[0].Price` may return undefined because you're passing `success` and `productCode` properties, but not `Price`.

Comment: @Tetsuya Yamamoto I have made some changes in script so would you kindly look at it & tell me what should i change in my code to achieve the expected output?